# PHP connect variable with a string in a link

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP,I have a variable that is a website link.

```
$siteurl='iza.kwickmenu.com'
```

And I need to connect to this link to a string,so that I can get a new link:

```
iza.kwickmenu.com/img/logo.png
```

I tied those code:

```
<img src="$siteurl.'/img/logo.png'" alt='logo'>
```

but failed,any friend can help?

Comment: You'll need the `http://` or `https://` at the beginning for it to work.

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $siteurl ?>/img/logo.png" alt='logo'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code

```
<?php 
$siteurl="http://iza.kwickmenu.com";
$pngurl=$siteurl.'/img/logo.png';
echo "<img src='".$pngurl."' />";
?>
```